# XAML: SystemColors of a SolidColorBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

I am searching for the `SystemColors` of a `SolidColorBrush`, but unfortunately, I cannot find any lists.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Orange" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
```

In this case, I am trying to set a mouse over effect and it works fine. But I want to know the `SystemColors` code snippet to change the `BorderBrush` of a selected item in my `DataGrid`.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** [solution at msdn.microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx)

Comment: Do you need the value of the color? `SystemColors.HighlightBrush` is what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes, I am searching for the value. But your code does not change the edge, the `BorderBrush` of a selected item. It does not change anything. Is there a Microsoft list of all values?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for those values [SystemColors](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemColors.cs) is the class you're after. It has a set of properties key and values for all system specific colors(brushes).

Comment: This is a nice list, thank you for that. But actually I am just seaching for this... `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBORDERBRUSH}" Color="Red" />` --> as you may know, THIS is not working. Where can I find this kind of code?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrush` and `SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush`. If am wrong please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I am looking for. I finally found this list online: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx). Somewhere in this list, there should be me solution.